# adding bootstrap 4.5.1 rtl to laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

i want to build a laravel 8 application that uses bootstrap and its so simple until this part but i want to add the rtl version of bootstrap to that . so what i did was this :

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install
npm run dev
```

and what i get is the bootstrap is running fine . and what i did for the the rtl bootstrap is this in `layout.blade.php`:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-vus3nQHTD+5mpDiZ4rkEPlnkcyTP+49BhJ4wJeJunw06ZAp+wzzeBPUXr42fi8If" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

but yet again elements are left to right . any idea how to do that and what i am doing wrong

Comment: If the rtl bootstrap loaded successfully, then simply add body{ direction: rtl; }; can you post a screenshot for the result?

Comment: Have you added/updated js link for rtl as you did for the css ?
if not then add/replace the bootstrap js cdn with this `<script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a9xOd0rz8w0J8zqj1qJic7GPFfyMfoiuDjC9rqXlVOcGO/dmRqzMn34gZYDTel8k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Ref: [Bootstrap 4 RTL](https://bootstrap.rtlcss.com)

Comment: yes i added the js too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not done properly.

Because the library twice bootstrap sound in its layer, (RTL and LTR)

You should only use one (NPM or CDN)

Version 4.2 is not available for npm

[image]

- Install Bootstrap Version 4.5 (Latest Version)

> ```
> npm i bootstrap-v4-rtl
> ```

- install another version

> ```
> npm i bootstrap-v4-rtl@x.y.z
> ```